# Where to find examples and/or documentation for Ext.Net MVC4 Razor?

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, ext.net

I've found tutorials for [ASP.NET MVC4 Razor](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4) and examples for [Ext.Net Webforms](http://examples.ext.net/), and I've been trying to work it out on my own from there.

But is there anything out there that can show me Ext.Net MVC4 with Razor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ext.NET team is about to release a new MVC specific Examples Explorer. Should be online within the next day or two, but will require the upcoming v2.1 release if you want to run any samples.

The samples will be available at http://mvc.ext.net/